# Updating records in a Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

at the first, I should explain my scenario to declare what I will do:

I want to merge records in one Table and then save them in another table.
Why?
I had a very complex query which needs long time to run and give back the result. I decided to divide this query into two query and save the resulat of the first query into a table and then the second query use the new generated  table 
the source table is often updated and the generated table must be generated too
If I use this code on my VBA this error occured:
Error 3010 Table already exist

```
Set db = CurrentDb
  ssql = "SELECT DISTINCT tb_KonzeptDaten.DFCC,  " _
  & "tb_KonzeptDaten.OBD_Code AS Konzept_Obd,tb_KonzeptDaten.DFC " _
  & "INTO Test_Table FROM tb_KonzeptDaten"
  db.Execute ssql, dbFailOnError
  RecordsUpdated = db.RecordsAffected
```

have you any idea ? do we have another SQL statement to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the table in VBA if it already exists and then run the query.

```
tblName = "TableX"
tbl = DLookup("Name", "MSysobjects", "Type=1 and Name='" & tblName & "'")

If Not IsNull(tbl) Then
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tbl
End If
```

Or

```
Set db = CurrentDb
ssql = "DELETE FROM Test_Table"
db.Execute ssql, dbFailOnError

ssql = "INSERT INTO Test_Table SELECT DISTINCT tb_KonzeptDaten.DFCC,  " _
  & "tb_KonzeptDaten.OBD_Code AS Konzept_Obd,tb_KonzeptDaten.DFC " _
  & "FROM tb_KonzeptDaten"
db.Execute ssql, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Remou but I mean without Delete.Is it generally possible?

Comment: You cannot overwrite, you can append to an existing table, or you can delete and recreate. In general, it is better to run a delete query and then append to the existing table. I do not see how you can avoid some sort of delete unless you want to keep the data in Test_table and add to it.